# How can I import the reference of content to table of content of the imported PDF in the global document?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfpages

I'm writing a bilingual book combined with ENG - FR
the idea is to generate the first book in FR then import it inside the ENG one,
all is good with this code

```
\AtEndDocument{\includepdf[pages=-]{21stskills4testers_FR_just_for_test.pdf}}
```

But the problem, the reference to table of content of the imported PDF (FR) disappears.

Can I import a PDF without loosing it's reference of content ? [image]

Comment: No. I don't believe you can do this. But I believe there are some tricks discussed somewhere around here which might let you add some links back in. It might, however, be easier not to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Do you mean tricks in the PDF it self after being generated ? or I call 2 projects at the same time ?

Comment: I *think* I've seen discussion of post-processing the PDF to restore some of the links. But it is certainly a smoother ride if you do it as one document.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pdfpages` you cannot import the TOC, but you can recreate it. But I don't think this is worth the effort in your case. Especially not, when you are writing both  versions of the book. In this case I would consider `\include` instead of `\includepdf`. See the example below.

Anyway, assuming that you have only the PDF (not the LaTeX source), then it might be reasonable to recreate the TOC like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[
  pages=-,
  addtotoc={%
    1, section, 1, aaa, sec:aaa,
    2, section, 1, bbb, sec:bbb,
    3, section, 1, ccc, sec:ccc
    }%
]{dummy.pdf}

\end{document}
```

But since you are writing both versions of the book, and have the LaTeX source of both, the following approach is much better.

English version of your book. File `content-en.tex`.

```
\section{English}
\lipsum
```

French version of your book. File `content-fr.tex`.

```
\section{French}
\lipsum
```

And finally the main document, where you include both versions or just one or the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\include{content-en}
\include{content-fr}
\end{document}
```